# Is it possible to add image as a background to Listbox in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, background, listbox, background-image

I want to have an image as a background to a `Listbox`, but I am am only able to find out how to change background *color* of one.

Comment: Wouldn't the background image go under the text of the listbox? Wouldn't that make the text hard to read? Also from what I know you can't put an image as the background of a listbox. You can to use a `tk.Canvas` and build your own listbox widget from scratch in that canvas.

Comment: Another approach if you want more customized styling is to use something other than `tkinter`. `Gtk` and `PyQt` are two examples of other GUI modules for Python. Personally, I have much more experience with `Gtk` than with `PyQt`, and I know for a fact that it's possible to set image backgrounds for widgets when you use CSS to style your `Gtk` app. The downside is that both `Gtk` and `PyQt` are more complicated to use than `tkinter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to add an image as a background for the listbox.